# I need to get the value of first input then add +1 then put the sum to the on a textfield

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my code now but outputs NaN in acadyearTo:

jquery:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var sum = parseInt($('#acadyearFrom').val()) + 1;
$('#acadyearTo').val(sum);
 });
</script>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="acadyearFrom" maxlength="4"  id="acadyearFrom">
<input type="text" name="acadyearTo" maxlength="4" id="acadyearTo">
```

Comment: When using code in a question, please put all code into code blocks: usually, indent all code lines by 4 spaces (preferable), but for inline code on the same line as non-code, surround the code with backticks (`\``).

Comment: Note: I've rolled the question back to a previous revision. There is no need to add "solved". Accepting an answer marks it as such.

Comment: Btw, this isn't a php question; I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var sum = parseInt($('#acadyearFrom').val()) + 1; // getting data from one text box, converting into number and adding 1
$('#acadyearTo').val(sum); // setting data to another text box
```

Comment: it only return NaN as an answer

Comment: @S.michael You are getting NaN because you are getting the value from the first textbox when the page loads. At this time, the value of the textbox is undefined. Thus, parseInt(undefined) = NaN. The solution to this is that you need to bind this with some event. Something like when you click on a button, then the value from the first textbox is taken and assigned to the second textbox. Fiddle for your reference: jsfiddle.net/svu0krnw